# Concurrence in saving object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a APP, when the users has a time for acept one requisition, when he presses the button to accept, check before if there is already an object saved upon that request, which to me means someone had already accepted before the request, but I can not guarantee that two users fasten at the same time and overwrite each other.
Is my code:

```
if(object.fetch().getParseObject("requisition") == null){
       object.put("requisition", myObject);
       object.save();
}
```

Comment: I think ParseCloud will be better to use here.

Comment: I also thought of using the beforeSave (), but how do you know that the user's intention is to save in this particular field?

Comment: Seems like someone haven't done his homework: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers it's what You define will be checked. You program it, not the other way.